# Codeigniter Shopping Cart with ajax - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

First, I'd like to apologize for bringing up this subject again,
but I'm about to go bananas.
Everything worked swell but then I made something to screw up my code,
and now my store items won't add to the shopping cart -
And I get this error -
 `POST http://localhost/store/cart/add_item 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Here are the relevant functions to this problem,
Any help will be much, much appreciated.

Controller

```
    public function add_item() {
        if ($this->cart_model->validate_add_item() == TRUE) {
            if($this->input->post('ajax') != '1'){
                redirect('home'); 
            }else{
                echo 'true'; 
            }
           }
          }

  public function show_mini(){
      $this->load->view('inc/mini_cart_view');
}
```

Model

```
public function validate_add_item(){

    $id = $this->input->post('product_id');
    $cty = $this->input->post('quantity'); 

    $query = $this->db->select()->from('products')
    ->where('product_id', $id)->get('products', 1); 

    if($query->num_rows > 0){
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $data = array(
                'id'      => $id,
                'qty'     => $cty,
                'price'   => $row->price,
                'name'    => $row->name
            );
            $this->cart->insert($data); 
            return TRUE; 
        }
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('.activate_ajax').on('click', function() {

        var id = $(this).find('input[name=product_id]').val();
        var qty = $(this).find('input[name=quantity]').val();

        $.post("cart/add_item", {
            product_id: id,
            quantity: qty,
            ajax: '1'
        },
        function(data) {
            if (data == 'true') {
                $.get("cart/show_mini", function(cart) {
                    $(".shopping_cart").html(cart);
                });
            } else {
           console.log('No such product');
            }
        });
        return false;
```

HTML
(Only the form_open part..)

```
 <?= form_open('cart/add_item', $sub); ?> 
        <div class="prod_details_tab" id="ajax_main"> 
            <span id="form_style">
        <?= form_input('quantity', '1', $att); ?>
        <?= form_hidden('product_id', $v['product_id'], $id); ?>   
        <?= form_hidden('name', $v['product_name']); ?> 
        <?= form_hidden('price', $v['product_price']); ?>   
          </span>
            <a id="ajax_add" href="#"></a>
        <?= form_submit('action', 'Add to Cart'); ?>
            <a  href="<?= base_url() ?>home/product_page/<?= $v['product_id'] ?>/<?= $v['product_category_id'] ?>" class="prod_details">Details</a> 
        <?= form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` to find out what the error is

Comment: `$query = $this->db->select()->from('products')`
What are you selecting, i you want all fields then put `'*'` in `select('*')`.

Comment: check that you have `CSRF` protection enabled in `config.php` ?